# Moving Large Number of Wordpress posts from One wordpress site to another existing wordpress site

Tags: migration

I have a wordpress site which consists more than 2 Lakh Posts . I need to move this posts to another existing Wordpress Site which has more than 8 lakh Posts. 
How do i go about migrating this data.

Comment: You can use export option of wordpress `Dashboard -> tools -> export`. There choose posts and click button and your all posts will be export. And import your exported file where ever you want. That many posts may exceeds exported file size more than 2mb (default max size). For that you can increase max upload size limit from 2 mb to larger size from `php.ini` file.

Comment: What does *Lakh* means  ?

Comment: Thanks Rishabh , I've tried that . However the xml is generated with error . Do you have any other thoughts apart from this solution ? Appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress admin of the new site, go to Below Steps 
**For Export Steps**

1. Tools>Export(Choose What to export).

**Click “Download Export File” and save the file.**

1. Tools>Import.
2. Select “WordPress“, install the importer by clicking “Install” in the popup, and “Activate Plugin & Run Importer“.
3. select the file to upload (the one you just downloaded). Click “Upload file and import“